# How to create Elastic rope / Rubber band in box2d?

Tags: box2d, cocos2d

I am trying to create the rubber band type or elastic rope.

i ant to do something like bellow link.
http://heyalda.com/smash-turtle/

Thanks,

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171937/box2d-elastic-rope-joint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one will write the code for you so I think you would be hard up getting an answer. Luckily for you I searched for a tutorial for creating rope with box2d and cocos2d on google and found this really good tutorial on making a cut the rope type game

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14793/how-to-make-a-game-like-cut-the-rope-part-1

EDIT: iPhone game "climbers" 
https://github.com/haqu/climbers

It isn't exactly what you want. However, I'm sure this is a lot better than what you have now :)

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks For helping but i found this tutorial already i will try to do.Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: You are welcome :) another game you could look for is "climbers" I think it's called. It too has a rope where you could read the code to try create your own. Check the answer because I added the link for you